# How can I compare same type of variables in one condition?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

It's my statment for example,I dont want '&&' every condition in the statment.Is there simple way to compare all object in one condition like in the exam?

```
int a = 3;
if(a!=0 && a!=1 && a!=2) // Example Statement
```

I looking for this type a thing.

```
if(a!=0,1,2)
```

Is there a function or a condition style, or something like that?

Comment: Nope. Just do it like you are. Or use `a < 0 || a > 2`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Providing `a` is an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `!Arrays.asList(1,2,3).contains(a);`

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. This has a lot of overhead compared to the simple check from the OP.